# How to speed to page with lots of images load time

Tags: php, performance

When running this on the page it takes a long time for the page to load and halts then in one shot displays everything is there any way i can fast?

things i've tried is saving that portion into a .html and displaying it from there still does not make a difference, also tried using lozad.js to load the images still does the same thing

```
<div class='person-videos-text'>    
            <div class="row">

            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recentTreningVideos))
                {
                    $TrendImageURL = $row['youtubethumbnail'];
                    $TrendSongName = $row['musicvideotitle'];
                    $TrendCleanSongname = $row['songname'];

                    $name = $row['youtubethumbnail'];

                    $rippedUrl = explode("/",$name);

                    //print_r($rippedUrl);

                    $hostt = $rippedUrl[0];
                    $hostUrl = $rippedUrl[2];
                    $imageNameVi = $rippedUrl[3];
                    $imageNameUrl = $rippedUrl[4];
                    $imageType = $rippedUrl[5];
            ?>

             <div class="column trending">
                <div class="card">
                <a href="viewactors.php?songname=<?php echo $TrendCleanSongname; ?>">
                  <img class="trending-image-size" src="cached/<?php echo $imageNameUrl;?>/<?php echo $imageType; ?>" alt="John">
                  <div class="person-container">
                    <!--<h2>John Doe</h2>-->
                    <p class="title trending-title"><?php echo $TrendSongName; ?></p>
                    <!--<p>Some text that describes me lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.</p>
                    <p>example@example.com</p>
                    <p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>-->
                  </div>
                </a>
                </div>
              </div>

            <?php } ?>         
            </div>      
        </div>
```

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/

Comment: Use Ajax! Your page loads with 0 image but you call the images step by step using a timer.

Comment: You can use Jquery lazy loading, images will be loaded when it near the viewport. You need to resize your thumbnail images also, do not load the high-res images as your thumbnail. You can resize batch images here https://picrez.com